# condition statement in helm chart configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, configmap

I have the following `configmap-app.yaml` file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
  labels:
    {{- include "app.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
data:
  application.yaml: {{ (tpl (.Files.Get "files/application.yaml") . | quote ) }}
```

For `application.yaml` I need to add one config file or the other, based on a boolean flag:

```
{{ if .Values.validation.enabled }}
    # use first configmap
{{ else }}
    # use second configmap
{{ end }}
```

If validation.enabled=true then `application.yaml` should read from `files/application-first.yaml` and if validation.enabled=false, then it should read from `files/application-second.yaml`. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example/assumption seems correct, you just need to specify `second` file in the else section.

```
{{ if .Values.validation.enabled }}
    application.yaml: {{ (tpl (.Files.Get "files/application.yaml") . | quote ) }}
{{ else }}
    application.yaml: {{ (tpl (.Files.Get "files/application-second.yaml") . | quote ) }}
{{ end }}
```

Make sure to add a variable in the value file

```
validation:
  enabled: true
```